# How can I change schema structure in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a schema of the following view:

```
root
|-- indie_guarantees: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- indie_guarantee_ArrayType: array (nullable = true)
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | | | |-- _corr: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- end_reason: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- fact_end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- sum: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- sign: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- indie_guarantee: struct (nullable = true)
| | | |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- date: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- end_reason: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- fact_end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | |-- sum: string (nullable = true)
```

and I need to change it like this:

```
root
|-- indie_guarantees: array (nullable = true)
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | |-- indie_guarantee: array (nullable = true)
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
| | | | |-- _corr: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- end_reason: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- fact_end_date: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- sum: string (nullable = true)
| | | | |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
| | |-- sign: string (nullable = true)
```

Merge **indie_guarantee_ArrayType** (array) and **indie_guarantee**(struct) in one array and don't forget about **sign**

I've tried to do

```
df.withColumn("newColumn", coalesce("indie_guarantee_ArrayType", array("indie_guarantee")))
```

but it works incorrectly. It creates a new field not in **indie_guarantees**
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `coalesce` will choose the first column which is not null, so it could drop `indie_guarantee` completely, but you could use `array_union` instead

```py
df.withColumn("newColumn", array_union("indie_guarantee_ArrayType", array("indie_guarantee")))
```

Just keep in mind that `array_union` removes duplicates if any exists